# Bouncy Castle "encoded key spec not recognised"

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-web-services, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I'm encountering this particular error after running my jar in an amazon linux. It was working fine in my OsX. I'm using the same public and private key in both machines. The only difference is the java version which is

Machine where I made, test and compiled my script:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)

Amazon server:

> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.4.7.1.40.amzn1-x86_64 u55-b13)

This is the section of the script that's causing the error:

```
public PublicKey getPublicKey(String _file)
    throws
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException,
        InvalidKeySpecException,
        IOException
{
    X509EncodedKeySpec _spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(_getFileContents(_file));
    KeyFactory _keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(this._keyFactoryAlgo, this._provider);

    this._publicKey = _keyFactory.generatePublic(_spec);

    return this._publicKey;
}
```

GetFileContents:

```
private byte[] _getFileContents(String _fileName) throws IOException
{

    File _file = new File(_fileName);
    FileInputStream _fileStream = new FileInputStream(_file);

    byte[] _contents = new byte[(int) _file.length()];

    _fileStream.read(_contents);

    if(_fileStream != null)
    {
        _fileStream.close();
        _fileStream = null;
    }

    return _contents;
}
```

Here is the full error message:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328)
at xxx.CryptKey.getPublicKey(CryptKey.java:167)
at xxx.CryptSession.encryptWithPublicKey(CryptSession.java:316)
at xxx.Crypt.encrypt(Crypt.java:57)
at snippet.Snippet.main(Snippet.java:201)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Comment: perhaps is because the 2 different platforms have different encodings? there might be problems converting your string to byte[].

Comment: is there anyway i can confirm that? or maybe update one or the other?

Comment: i think you can use `Charset.defaultCharset()` to check the encodings.

Comment: i got `[*]DefaultCharset:UTF-8` on both

Comment: How `getFileContents()` is implemented? A **lot** of crypto questions here is actually about I/O and reading the file or input stream (im)properly.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I've have updated my question. I put the getFileContents there

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Yep that did the trick! Our system administrator manually copied and pasted those files which might destroyed the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed reading file incorrectly. You are ignoring the return value of the `InputStream.read()`. You should call this method in cycle because the individual call is not guaranteed to read the entire byte array.

You can read it manually:

```
int offset = 0;
int read =  _fileStream.read(_contents, 0, contents.length);
while (read > 0) {
    offset += read;
    read = _fileStream.read(_contents, offset , contents.length - offset );

}
```

Or you can wrap the underlying input stream into `DataInputStream` and just use [DataInputStream.readFully()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29) method.

Comment: Or [`Files.readAllBytes((new File(_filename)).toPath())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path))

Comment: I am facing the same problem as OP. If I generate a fresh private key using KeyPairGenerator it works fine. But if I use my previously generated key (which I am encrypting using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding and storing in keystore. Reading from keystore and decrypting before signing) I get the error. I checked the key bytes and it is exactly same as if it was when freshly generated.